# How to format result when query is executed from bash instead of PSQL shell?

Tags: postgresql, bash, psql

I am familiar with `\x auto` mode of PSQL and it works great when I make query from inside PSQL shell.

But I'm executing query from bash shell and psql is running inside a docker container.

How can I combine `\x auto` with `SELECT` query in such case ?

What I have already tried:

```sh
$ docker exec -it my_database psql -U iamuser -c "\x auto; SELECT * FROM mytable;"

Expanded display is used automatically.
\x: extra argument "select" ignored
\x: extra argument "*" ignored
\x: extra argument "from" ignored
\x: extra argument "mytable;" ignored
```

I also tried doing this, but no query results are not shown.

```sh
$ docker exec -it my_database psql -U iamuser -c "\x auto \n SELECT * FROM mytable;"

Expanded display is used automatically.
```

Is it possible to achieve this ? If yes, how ?

Comment: I think you need to specify `-c` twice

Comment: Alternatively, it seems you can also specify `-x` directly instead of `-c '\x auto'`